# How to determine if all polygons are contiguous by single point in SQL Server

Tags: sql, spatial-database

**I've been looking for some function that will consider geometries from a table.**

The selection would look something like this:

```
SELECT geom FROM mytable WHERE geoid IN (1, 10, 15, 30, 2)
```

How can I tell if the geometries are "contiguous" (sharing at least one point or boundary with no gaps, i.e. geometries are strung together with no breaks).

**For more clarity:**
Assume we use the "^" as a triangle and the SELECT statement above gives this result of three geometries touching and two touching geometries by themselves:
^^^ ^^
The goal is to determine that the above condition is not contiguous, but the following would be:
^^^^^

Comment: Probably this is hard to do with SQL Server, but if you convert the polygon coverage into a graph and that does not have isolated islands then all boundaries are connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the area of the `ST_Union` equals the sum of the areas of each polygon.  I think you can conclude there are no overlaps.

As I recall if you union two triangles whose corners touch, the result has two rings.

If you buffer the union by some small (epsilon) amount and the resulting geometry/geography has only one exterior ring,  I think you could conclude they are contiguous.

Comment: Thank you! Setting a buffer on all the shapes and use ST_Union, then count the shapes -- if the count is greater than 1, then the shapes (in combination) are not contiguous.